# How to highlight text on focus in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do you highlight a the text in a TextBox control in Windows Phone 7? I can't find a property setting on the control.

Is handling OnFocus event in the code-behind the only option?

Answer (score 2):

You can highlight text using TextBox.Select(int start, int length).

Comment: Thanks. But that is done in code-behind right? I was looking for some mark-up property.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a pretty great attached property that you can use to do this.  You can see an original description of the solution [of auto selecting text in a textbox](http://dnchannel.blogspot.com/2010/01/silverlight-3-auto-select-text-in.html) and also see [a project where I made user of it](http://wp7-developer.com/code-snippet/create-a-quick-and-simple-name-tag-with-elementname-binding/).